# Amazon Translate api call to determine available languages

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, aws-java-sdk

For Amazon Translate, using the API for Java, is there a way to determine the source and target languages available?

The documentation states that a `UnsupportedLanguagePairException` will be thrown if the `translateText` method of `AmazonTranslateClient` is called with an unsupported language pair.

Other than simply reading which language pairs are allowed in the documentation, is there an API call which returns **(1)** the language pairs allowed **or** **(2)** the source and target languages allowed?

Comment: Did find any information on this?

Comment: No I did not. Sorry.